# Diferença de null e outra proposição usando esse objeto null

Tags: java, operadores, nullpointerexception, null, condição

Se eu tenho um código, por exemplo:

```
if(window!=null && window.isOpen()){
   //todo
}
```

Se `window` for `null`, ele ainda vai tentar chamar a segunda proposição ou não verifica mais? Porque se ele tentar chamar, aí vai dar um `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A segunda não será chamada. Isso chama-se [*short circuit evaluation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) ([em português](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)). Quando a expressão já obtém um valor final garantindo, não tem porque continuar verificando o resto e a execução encerra. No caso como o operador relacional é um "AND" e os dois operando precisam ser verdadeiros para resultar em `true`, se o primeiro já for `false` já se sabe que a expressão É `false`.

Isso é equivalente a:

```
if (window != null) {
    if (window.isOpen()) {
       //todo
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/NonNull.java).

mas é uma forma mais concisa.

Esta é a técnica correta, e bastante usada, para garantir que o objeto não seja nulo. Primeiro se verifica se for nulo e depois de um operador "E" faz o que deseja, que só será executado se o primeiro for verdadeiro. Dá para ser criativo com muita coisa aí e usar a mesma técnica para várias coisas.

Há casos que se usa o `||`. nesse caso se o primeiro for `true` o segundo não será executado, já que em um operador "OR" basta um ser verdadeiro para nem precisar verificar o outro operando.

Comment: Seria interessante até pro enriquecimento da resposta, quem negativou dizer onde está o problema.

Answer (score 5):

Para que entre no if, ambas as condições precisam ser verdadeiras, se a primeira for `false`(ou seja, `windows == null`), ele ignorará a segunda e não entrará no if.

Veja este exemplo:

```
String b = null;

if(b != null && b.equals("")){
    System.out.println(b);
}else{
    System.out.println("b não atende as condições do if");
}
```

A saída será apenas a exibição da mensagem `b não atende as condições do if`, pois b é nulo.

Veja funcionando no [ideone](http://ideone.com/nnagN2).

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se procede, mas meu professor da faculdade falou que se você usar & (um &) ele verifica os dois, e se você usar && (dois &) ele verificar o primeiro e se ja der negação ele não verifica o segundo.

Referencia:
http://diegonascimentojava.blogspot.com.br/2013/09/operadores-logicos-and-or-xor.html

Comment: É isso, eu também estou em dúvida, pois algumas vezes no android um código parecido ainda era chamado...

Comment: `&` é um `eager operator`, significa que toda a expressão será avaliada, independente que no início da expressão já se sabe que o resultado final pode ser `true` ou `false`, ele continuará a execução. `&&` é um `short-circuit operator`, conforme na resposta do @bigown, isso significa que caso ele identifique que independente do resto da análise da expressão o resultado ainda seja X, então ele já retorna X para não perder tempo com isso

Comment: Acredito que essa resposta esteja parcialmente errada. O motivo não é bem esse, ou até é, mas não está explicando o motivo de não avaliar o segundo operando. Curiosamente negativaram a minha resposta, alguém deve estar confundindo as coisas do que é certo e errado.

Comment: Entendo que esteja de fato errada. Uma pequena parcela dela é "verdadeira", mas é uma questão colateral. O nível de atuação dos dois tipos de operador é completamente diferente.