# Existe alguma forma de 'break' no If?

Tags: php, if, condição

Queria saber se existe algum tipo de 'break' no `IF`. Minha dúvida se baseia no exemplo abaixo. Quando a função `b()` retorna `false` todas comparações seguintes não são executadas. Pensava que a condição iria comparar todos os valores e retornar o resultado.

Posso estar falando besteira, mas parece que lança um 'break' logo quando encontra um resultado que não supra a condição, algo parecido com um `throw`.

---

```
$a = function(){ echo 'a'; return 1; };
$b = function(){ echo 'b'; return 1; };
$c = function(){ echo 'c'; return 1; };

if( $a() && $b() && $c() )
echo 'sucesso';
```

<sub>**output** : `a b c sucesso`</sub>

---

```
$a = function(){ echo 'a'; return 1; };
$b = function(){ echo 'b'; return 0; };
$c = function(){ echo 'c'; return 1; };

if( $a() && $b() && $c() )
echo 'sucesso';
```

<sub>**output** : `a b`</sub>

---

Meu caso era usar um `if` onde a terceira condição dependesse das outras duas como verdadeiras, poupando `if + if`. No exemplo acima funcionou como esperado, mas realmente foi uma novidade pra mim.

Comment: Também já notei isso no C# , por exemplo quando quero comparar a propriedade de um objeto, e este objeto está `null`, o C# lança uma `exception`, para isto comparo antes, no mesmo `if(objeto != null && objeto.propriedade == valor)`, não ocorre a `exception`, a resposta do @bigown me ajudou a esclarecer isto também

Comment: @MarcoGiovanni isso é proposital até para resolver esse tipo de questão. Sem o *short circuit* o código teria que ser complicado.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Existe uma coisa chamada [*short-circuit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). Os operadores relacionais operam desta forma. Eles vão avaliando até já terem certeza do resultado. Quando os demais operandos não podem mais alterar o resultado não importa os seus valores ele não tenta mais avaliar nada e toma a decisão.

Isso é útil porque dá melhor performance e evita possíveis efeitos colaterais que eventualmente devem ser evitados mesmo dependendo da condição anterior. Então:

```
if ( $a() && $b() && $c() ) fazAlgo;
```

É o mesmo que:

```
if ( $a() )
    if ( $b() )
        if ( $c() )
            fazAlgo;
```

Ou seja, se não entrar no primeiro `if` não vai entrar nos demais. Assim fica mais fácil de ver. E curiosamente muito programador escreve o segundo exemplo sem perceber que poderia escrever em uma única linha.

Como o **AND** exige que todos operandos sejam verdadeiros para resultar em verdadeiro quando uma dá falso, é impossível que os outros revertam a situação, não tem porque avaliar os outros.

O mesmo pode ocorrer com **OR**. Só que neste caso a situação é diferente. Esse operador exige que apenas um operando seja verdadeiro para o resultado final ser verdadeiro. Se o primeiro der verdadeiro, ele não vai mais olhar os demais:

```
if( $a() || $b() || $c() ) fazAlgo;
```

É o mesmo que:

```
if ( $a() ) fazAlgo;
else if ( $b() ) fazAlgo; //faz algo igual
else if ( $c() ) fazAlgo; //tem que ser igual
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/ShortCircuit.php).

Basta o `$a()` dar `true` e `$b()` e `$c()` nem serão executados. Se ele der `false` é claro que vai avaliar `$b()`, aí a decisão se vai avaliar `$c()` depende do resultado dele.

Isso pode ser observado com outros operadores relacionais (pelo menos em algumas linguagens).

Tem linguagem que não adota isso.

Os operadores de bit (ex.: `&`, `|`) não possuem a característica de fechar o circuito e todos executam sempre. Inclusive eles são usados quando a característica não é desejada.

[Há um pergunta com um exemplo clássico do seu uso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/148982/101). Você tem um primeiro operando que verifica se uma condição é satisfeita. O segundo operando só funcionará corretamente se a primeira for verdadeira. Típico de verificação de um objeto é nulo antes de acessá-lo.

Comment: Eu realmente não sabia dessa. Muito elucidativo o exemplo. Valeu Big

Comment: Seguindo o exemplo do `or`, seria algo como `if( ($a() or $b()) && $c() )`, *$a* **ou** *$b* como verdadeiro e *$c* como verdadeiro. Correto?

Comment: Se entendi, sim. Nesse caso tem duas expressões. A primeira será verdadeira se um dos dois operando forem verdadeiros, não importa qual. Então se `$a`()` der verdadeiro, nem vai olhar `$b()`. E por consequência vai olhar `$c()` para ter certeza que o resultado final será verdadeiro. Se `$a()` der falso, vai olhar `$b()`. Se este der falso tb, nem vai olhar `$c()`, já é garantido que vai dar falso.

Comment: Isso mesmo... Manda essa resposta pra DOC do PHP :)

Comment: @PapaCharlie Se você ver como fica um código minificado, verá que tem muitos `if($var1 == true && $var2 = explode(' ', $var3) && $var4 = $var2[1])`

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert isso é minificado? nem quero ver o não minificado :)

Comment: @bigown kkk, verdade seria `$a`, `$b`, `$c`, e `== 1`

Answer (score 1):

Sim, o argumento passado no break você sai de um nível. Caso tenha um foreach e um if:

```
foreach ( $var as $key )
{
  if ( $key == 0 )
  {
    #code...
    break(2);
  }
}
```

Essa forma vc interrompe tb o foreach. Da forma que passou no exemplo poderia ser usado o switch como alternativa

```
switch (variable) {
    case 'value':
        # code...
        break;

    default:
        # code...
        break;
}
```

Comment: Acho que não seria bem essa dúvida. Sei que há `break` no laço e no switch. A questão é o IF.