# Diferença entre If e IIf

Tags: vb.net, if

Em VB.NET, qual é a diferença do uso do `If` e do `IIf` nestas condições?

```
If Condicao Then
    x()
Else
    y()
End If

IIf(Condicao, x(), y())
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Comando `If`

O `If` é um comando (*statement*). Ele decide se vai executar um bloco de comandos baseado em uma expressão booleana. Ele pode decidir entre um bloco ou outro se houver a parte do `Else`. O primeiro bloco é executado se o resultado da expressão contida no `If` der verdadeiro. E executará o segundo bloco se der falso.

## Função `IIf()`

O [`IIf()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/27ydhh0d(v=vs.90)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) é uma função. Então a primeira grande diferença é que ela gera um resultado. Ela decide o que vai executar baseado na expressão booleana usada como primeiro argumento. Ela não tem blocos de código nem para o resultado verdeiro, nem para o falso. O que existe é um valor que será usado como retorno. O segundo argumento será retornado pela função se a expressão booleana for verdadeira. O terceiro argumento será retornado se ela resultar em falso. Obviamente que esse valor pode ser composto por uma expressão qualquer.

A função só pode ser usada com `Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic`.

## Diferenças

Mas tem uma diferença fundamental. Todas as três expressões dos argumentos da função são executados. Um dos dois resultados não será usado, mas haverá execução. Isso pode gerar efeitos colaterais indesejados (ou desejados, depende do objetivo). Pelo menos é o que diz a documentação. Não consegui construir um exemplo igual ao da pergunta que isso fosse verdade. Consegui o exemplo da documentação. Não me pergunte porque ocorre o curto-circuito em uma situação e em outra situação não ocorre.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/wJhzV0). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NLlISF). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/If.vb).

Nesses dois exemplos não muda muita coisa já que o resultado do `IIf()` é descartado. Na verdade os resultados de `x()` e `y()` também são. E note que essas funções precisam retornar alguma coisa. Não pode ser uma sub-rotina sem retorno. O `IIf()` aceita. O que vai mudar não pode ser determinado pelo que está na pergunta. É importante se o que `x()` e `y()` executam geram efeito colateral. Se sim, então algo diferente ocorrerá já que na função ambos serão executados.

Obviamente que a função tende ser um pouco mais lenta, não só porque funções impõe um *overhead* (o compilador poderia otimizar) mas principalmente porque manda executar algo que talvez não sirva para nada, mesmo que não gere efeito colateral.

## Operador `If()`

Note que a função é considerada obsoleta. Prefira usar o operador [`If()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/if-operator?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) para o mesmo resultado. Funciona essencialmente igual mas fazendo [*short circuit*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154056/101) dessas expressões, ou seja o argumento que não precisa do resultado nem é executado. Isso é o mais comum que se deseja. Mas se tiver algum motivo que queira que a execução da outra expressão seja executada mesmo assim, então pode usar a função.

O operador tem uma vantagem extra em relação à função. A função sempre retorna um `Object` e pode precisar uma conversão. O operador retorna o tipo usado nas duas expressões de resultado. Então se o segundo e o terceiro operando for uma *string*, o resultado de toda expressão `If()` será do tipo `String`. A função até pode fazer a conversão implícita em alguns casos, mas apenas será do tipo esperado depois da conversão necessária. Isso se usar `Option Strict Off`.

O operador `If()` é mais próximo do comando `If` no ponto da execução. O operador é o mesmo que o [operador condicional do C# (`? :` )](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17398/101).

O operador pode ser usado com dois operandos. Aí ele [funciona como o null-coalescing](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44133/101).

O operador não pode ser usado solto, precisa estar em um lugar que espera uma expressão.

```
Console.WriteLine(If(Condicao, x(), y()))
```

Comment: Só para dar a cobertura, o `IIf` também pode ser usado para verificador nulo, por exemplo, `IIf(SeIssoForNulo, UseIsso)`.