# Diferença entre a instrução If e o operador If

Tags: vb.net, if, operadores

Quais são as diferenças entre a [instrução If](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/752y8abs.aspx) e o [operador If](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx) no VB.NET?

```
If(Condicao, x(), y())
```

---

```
If Condicao Then
    x()
Else
    y()
End If
```

Comment: Não é a mesma? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154506/101

Comment: Você leu a resposta? Lá fala do operador