# Como evitar o erro "Cannot read property ... of undefined"?

Tags: javascript, exceção, undefined

Considerando o seguinte código:

```js
var a = {};

if (a.b.c !== undefined) {
  console.log("definido!");
} else {
  console.log("indefinido!");
}
```

Existe alguma forma de fazer a verificação de cada propriedade sem ter que testar uma a uma?

O que eu quero é o resultado de um `if` parecido com o seguinte, porém simplificado:

```js
var a = {};

if (a !== undefined && a.b !== undefined && a.b.c !== undefined) {
  console.log("definido!");
} else {
  console.log("indefinido!");
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Não gosto muto desta solução, mas pode capturar a exceção que será gerada por causa do erro:

```js
var a = {};

try {
    console.log(a.b.c);
} catch (e) {
    console.log("indefinido");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Object/PropertyUndefined.js).

Se quiser só simplificar sem eliminar a verificação individual pode se valer do [*short-circuit*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154056/101), se for só aninhamento de objetos complexos, se qualquer dos membros aninhados verificados forem escalares pode dar falso negativo:

```js
var a = {};

if (a && a.b && a.b.c) {
    console.log("definido!");
} else {
    console.log("indefinido!");
}

a = { b : { c: {} } };

if (a && a.b && a.b.c) {
    console.log("definido!");
} else {
    console.log("indefinido!");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Object/PropertyUndefined2.js).

Também pode criar uma abstração. Pode criar uma função ou usar uma pronta que faça o trabalho pesado.

Tem mais umas possibilidades, mas é gambiarra demais.

Comment: Problema da segunda abordagem é que se o valor de `a`, `a.b` ou `a.b.c` for **`false`**, 0 ou string vazia a saída vai ser indefinido

Comment: @jbueno é verdade, fiz a ressalvo

Comment: bigown e @jbueno Eu sei que foge um pouco da pergunta, mas vocês acham que [assim](http://pastebin.com/31xw9bPp) fica muito ruim?

Comment: @Sorack não sei dizer se é abuso do `Object.prototype` porque tenhho pouca experiência com JS, acho que não. Me parece que neste caso poderia eliminar a captura de exceção e verificar cada propriedade e é indefinida. Não que esteja errado, mas odeio se valer de exceção para resolver problemas que podem ser resolvidos com um mecanismo melhor. Não gosto da sintaxe. Eu encapsularia uma das duas soluções que te passei em uma função simples (a primeira funciona em todos casos)

Comment: @bigown entendi, fiz uma alteração pra não precisar me valer da exceção. Value mesmo, caso tenha curiosidade ficou [assim](http://pastebin.com/tZHWPz3f). Usei recursão pra chegar no resultado

Answer (score 9):

O nome deste recurso é *null propagation* e isso não existe no JavaScript.

Você pode usar o [`lodash`](https://lodash.com) pra fazer algo similar. Ele tem uma função chamada [`get`](https://lodash.com/docs#get), que recebe como parâmetro o objeto, as propriedades que você quer acessar e o valor *default* para o retorno, caso não seja possível encontrar as propriedades especificadas.

```js
// Exemplo onde a propriedade não existe

var a = {};
var result = _.get(a, 'b.c', 'Indefinido');
console.log(result);

// Exemplo onde a propriedade existe

var obj = { innerObj: { innerObj1: 'Teste' } };
var valor = _.get(obj, 'innerObj.innerObj1', 'Indefinido');
console.log(valor);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: obrigado por nomear o recurso. Sabendo o nome consegui ver que tem uma discussão pra que tenha um recurso para o que eu estou querendo no ES7.

Comment: Sim, eu vi isso também há uns dias, mas não consegui achar informações relevantes de fontes confiáveis, então achei melhor não citar.

Comment: Agora já tem o recurso. Chamaram de "encadeamento opcional".

Answer (score 9):

Acabei usando as informações das 3 respostas propostas até então. Lendo a resposta do *@Linq* vi que o nome do recurso é *null propagation* e que, apesar de não existir no JavaScript, possui grandes chances de ser implementado em um futuro próximo.

Partindo do princípio acima, levei em consideração a resposta do *@RobertoFagundes* e decidi utilizar uma função para isso.

Vendo a resposta do @Maniero utilizei os conceitos que ele apresentou e cheguei na seguinte resolução temporária (até implementarem no JavaScript):

```js
Object.prototype.hasProperty = function(signature) {
  var finalProperty = this;
  var property;
  var child;

  if (signature === undefined) {
    return true;
  }

  if (signature instanceof String) {
    signature = signature.split('.');
  }

  if (signature.constructor !== Array) {
    signature = [signature];
  }

  if (signature.length === 0) {
    return true;
  }

  property = signature.shift();
  child = this[property]; 

  if (child === undefined) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return child.hasProperty(signature);
  }
}

var a = {b: {c: {}}};

if (a.hasProperty(['b', 'c'])) {
  console.log("definido!");
} else {
  console.log("indefinido!");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Você pode utilizar uma função recursiva para realizar este trabalho, desta forma:

```js
function verificarArrayUnsigned(array){
  var isUnsigned = false;
  if (typeof array !== "unsigned"){
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
      if (typeof array[i] === "array"){
        isUnsigned = verificarArrayUnsigned(array[i]);
      } else {
        if (typeof array[i] === "unsigned"){
          isUnsigned = true;
        }
      }
      if (isUnsigned){
        break;
      }
    }
  } else {
    isUnsigned = true;
  }
  
  return isUnsigned;
}
```

Nesta função você pode passar tanto um array quanto uma variável.

Answer (score 3):

O `TypeError` de mensagem *“Cannot read property … of undefined”* é lançado quando se tenta acessar uma propriedade em algum valor do tipo `undefined` ou `null`.

As outras respostas desta pergunta indicam diversos artifícios para resolver problema erro em acessos encadeados.

A partir do ECMAScript 2020, pode-se utilizar a sintaxe do [encadeamento opcional](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/486360/69296), que faz curto circuito avaliando a expressão para `undefined` assim que o acesso de propriedade a `null` ou `undefined` é efetivado. Ao utilizar o `?.` ao invés de `.` para acesso, o erro em questão não é lançado.

Exemplo:

```js
const obj = {
  super: {
    nested: {
      prop: 'Value'
    }
  }
};

if (obj?.super?.nested?.prop) {
  console.log('`obj.super.nested.prop` existe.');
}

// Note o operador lógico NOT (verifica que não existe)
//  ↓
if (!obj?.super?.nested?.undefinedProp) {
  console.log('`obj.super.nested.undefinedProp` NÃO existe.');
}
```

Não irei me alongar muito na sintaxe, já que esse assunto já foi tratado [nesta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/486360/69296). Também tem a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Comment: Na época que fiz a pergunta não existia ainda o encadeamento opcional em JS (ele até é citado em alguma das respostas). Dei um +1 por deixar a questão mais completa! Obrigado!