# Operador "and" para atribuição em classes

Tags: php, operadores

Olhando alguns repositórios do GitHub encontrei este repositório para [geração de boletos com php](https://github.com/fredroo/openboleto) e dentro da classe `Cedente` me chamou a atenção o uso da palavra `and` dentro da função `construct` [neste arquivo](https://github.com/fredroo/openboleto/blob/master/src/OpenBoleto/Agente.php#L85).

O operador `and` é utilizado para comparações e também pode ser escrito como `&&` como o `if` no exemplo abaixo;

```
if (x = 10 and y = 20) { ...
```

Neste arquivo mostrado qual a função do `and`?

> ```
> $endereco and $this->setEndereco($endereco);
> ```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A mesma que no `if`, afinal esse é um operador booleano, ele pode ser aplicado em [qualquer expressão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168177/101) que exija um resultado verdadeiro ou falso, ele não precisa estar em um `if` como muita gente acha. Não entendo porque pensam que o `+` pode ser usado em qualquer lugar e o `&` ou `and` não pode.

Como o `and` usa a [técnica de curto circuito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154056/101) o segundo operando só será executado se o primeiro der verdadeiro. Então se a variável do primeiro operando é nula, ela é falsa (coisa horrorosa, mas assim é o PHP), então a atribuição não será executada. Se ele tiver algum valor então ela é verdadeira, então a atribuição do segundo operando será executado.

Tenho a impressão que seu uso ali é desnecessário, porque se não tivesse esse mecanismo iria atribuir nulo para algo que deve ser nulo mesmo. Talvez seja uma tentativa de otimização, mas se a otimização é necessária, deveria fazer em outra linguagem.

[Veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44741/101).