# Variação de while com scanf()

Tags: c, while, scanf

O que significa esse trecho de código?

```
while(scanf("%d", &variavelA) && variavelA )
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O `while` irá executar enquanto o resultado da condição dele for verdadeiro (ou 1). Logo, enquanto `scanf("%d", &variavelA) && variavelA` resultar em 1.

Nesse caso a função [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) vai retornar 1 quando um inteiro for lido (`%d`). O resultado dessa função irá fazer um AND lógico (`&&`) com `variavelA`. 
O resultado desse AND lógico só vai ser 0 caso o `scanf` retorne 0 ou o valor lido para `variavelA` seja 0.

Veja tabela verdade para AND lógico (&&):

```
0 && 0 == 0
0 && 1 == 0
1 && 0 == 0
1 && 1 == 1
```

Logo, o resultado só será 1 (executar `while`) caso ambas entradas sejam 1 (ler um inteiro e ele não ser 0, nesse exemplo).

Caso queira testar:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int variavelA = 0;
    while(int i = scanf("%d", &variavelA) && variavelA){
        printf("%d", variavelA);
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Vocë usou `std::cout` no seu exemplo mas a pergunta é sobre C e não C++.

Comment: Correção feita. Muito obrigado por ter editado a "tabela" também.

Comment: De nada! Eu ia fazer uma tabela mesmo, como você fez, só que usando essa página que alguém passou por aqui: [ASCII Table Generator](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/), que é bem útil às vezes, mas, no fim achei que assim ficaria melhor.

Answer (score 5):

```
scanf("%d", &variavelA)
```

Está manando ler no console um dado que deverá ser compatível com um número decimal. O valor será colocado na variável `variavelA` através da sua [referência (`&`)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125793/101). Ela retornará o número de dados lidos corretamente, portanto espera-se que retorne o valor 1, embora possa eventualmente vir maior que isto. Se falhar a leitura o retorno será 0.

O `while` é um comando que determina que o bloco a seguir deverá ser repetido enquanto a condição dentro dos parênteses seja verdadeira. note que o mais legível é ter uma espaço entre o comando e a abertura do parêntese para não confundir com uma função. Será verdadeiro sempre que a expressão total ali dentro seja diferente de 0. O 0 é reservado para falso e portando um resultado final 0 fará com que o bloco seguinte de comandos não seja executado mais.

A condição é composta por duas subexpressões, a primeira é i `scanf()` já explicado e já sabe se dá 0 ou um número maior. A segunda subexpressão verifica o valor digitado, portanto para ser verdadeiro não poderá ser digitado o valor 0. Como há o [operador `&&`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190579/101) ambas expressões precisam ser diferentes de 0 para que o resultado final seja diferente de 0, e só assim continua executando. A segunda subexpressão só será executada se a primeira fora verdadeira, por um conceito chamado [curto-circuito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/202635/101).

Provavelmente queria fazer o contrário, sair do laço quando isso for verdadeiro, ou seja, ele fica repetindo enquanto o dado digitado não é válido. Assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int variavelA = 0;
    printf("Digite um número maior que zero: ");
    while (!scanf("%d", &variavelA) || !variavelA) {
        printf("Digite um número maior que zero: ");
        getchar();
    }
    printf("%d", variavelA);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/rWepXH). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/jtlvyaxx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/ScanConditional.c).

Comment: Em C esse operador, _address of_ pega o endereço da variável. &x indica o endereço de x e não uma _referência_. Referências existem em C++ e são indicadas pelo mesmo símbolo, *&* numa declaração. Sobre `scanf()` entenda que o retorno pode ser negativo, nos casos de erro ou EOF. Talvez possa reescrever essa parte. Não é como descreveu.

Answer (score -1):

```
  while(scanf("%d", &variavelA) && variavelA )
```

é um erro.

**Uma explicação linear do que acontece, e um pouco mais formal:**

Sobre o comando em si, o **`while`** tem uma condição e um corpo, um comando que vai ser executado enquanto a condição for verdadeira.

#### Um programa completo em torno disso

Podia ser algo assim

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int A = 0;
    while (scanf("%d", &A) && A )
        printf("Valor de A: %d\n", A);
}
```

E o efeito será mostrar o valor de `A` enquanto a condição for verdadeira. O corpo do `while` pode ser vazio, e é igualmente válido escrever

```
    while (scanf("%d", &A) && A );
```

ou

```
     while (scanf("%d", &A) && A ){};
```

se a lógica assim o permitir: muitas vezes  se quer apenas incrementar um contador até uma  condição e a expressão é suficiente e o comando acaba suprimido. Mas muitas vezes o cara colocou o `;` por engano também ;) e é só um erro

#### sobre a expressão

Em `C` zero é `false`. Só isso. Só zero. Qualquer outro valor é verdadeiro numa expressão. Se `A` é uma variável então `if (A)` é falso se e somente se `A` for `0`. E só nesse caso. Qualquer expressão em `C` pode ser usada assim: `if (42)` é `true`, `if (-1)` é `true`, `if (EOF)` é `true` porque `EOF` é em geral `-1` e apenas `0` é `false`.

O operador `&&` é o `AND` lógico e junta expressões, avaliando para `true` se as duas expressões forem `true`. Numa situação assim se a primeira expressão já for `false` a seguinte não é avaliada. Isso é meio óbvio, mas estamos falando de programação: isso quer dizer que por exemplo numa condição

```
int res = f(A) && g(B) && h(C) && i(D);
```

Se alguma dessas funções retornar zero as que vem depois não vão ser chamadas e isso é importante: permite a noção de pré-requisito: `h(C)` poderia depender de `f()` e `g()` não retornarem `0`.

#### De volta ao programa: a expressão `scanf("%d", &A) && A`

`scanf()` pode retornar `-1` em caso de erro ou `EOF`, e um valor entre `0` e o total de especificadores, que são aquelas coisas que começam por `%` e não por `%%`. Por exemplo

```
    scanf("%d;%d;%f;%d",...)
```

pode retornar `-1, 0, 1, 2, 3 ou 4`.

E aí está o problema da expressão como escrita lá em cima: `scanf("%d",&A)` pode retornar `0` se não ler nada, e isso é `false` e encerraria o loop sem testar o valor de `A` e estaria `OK`. Mas se der erro ou voltar `EOF` isso vai dar `true` e vai usar o valor de `A` que foi lido no loop anterior para o teste, e isso é um erro que atinge um certo número de programas de iniciantes e mesmo alguns de profissionais.

#### `&` em C

Como prefixo de uma variável o `&` é o operador *address of*. `C` não tem referências como `C++`, que usa o mesmo símbolo para indicar referências.

`scanf()` não aloca memória e por isso espera um endereço para transferir os valores *scanned*. Por isso quando é um tipo primitivo como um `int` ou `float` é preciso usar o operador `&` para passar para `scanf()` o endereço da variável e não o valor dela, como em

```
    int A = 0;
    while (scanf("%d", &A) and A )
        printf("Valor de A: %d\n", A);
```

e assim `scanf()` tem o endereço de `A` para transferir o que for lido.

Answer (score -2):

É um codigo meio redundante, significa que você está começando um loop enquanto o programa receber input do usuario, ou seja, será um loop infinito a não ser q bote um tratamento para tal nele. A repetição do `variavelA` realmente é redundante, sugiro tirar ou bota um tratamento para o EOF.

Quando você não usa nenhum valor no scanf, ele retorna EOF (normalmente -1), e caso tenha input, retorna 1. A questão aqui é que você ficará preso no loop a não ser q use um break durante o while para quebra-lo.

Comment: Não tem nada de redundante ou *loop* infinito aí. Há um erro de lógica provável.

Comment: Não há erro, ele pediu pra explicar o código, na minha opinião é redundante a parte que citei, e gera sim um loop assim se n houver uma quebra no while. Vi que a sua resposta ficou bem mais completa, então pelo menos a minha serve de complemento.