# Existe equivalente a AndAlso e OrElse no C#?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, característica-linguagem, operadores

No VB.NET existem dois operadores interessantes: o `AndAlso` e o `OrElse`.

Quando usados, a expressão lógica não é avaliada por inteiro de imediato.

Vejam o seguinte exemplo:

```
If (Not Usuario Is Nothing) And (Usuario.Idade = 18) Then
...
End If
```

Caso o objeto `Usuario` seja `Nothing`, uma `NullReferenceException` será disparada, mesmo com a verificação prévia. Esse problema poderia ser contornado assim:

```
If (Not Usuario Is Nothing) Then
    If (Usuario.Idade = 18) Then
        ...
    End If
End If
```

Porém, se trocarmos o operador para `AndAlso`, a exceção não será disparada, pois a parte da expressão que está após o `AndAlso` será avaliada somente caso a parte anterior seja `True`:

```
If (Not Usuario Is Nothing) AndAlso (Usuario.Idade = 18) Then
...
End If
```

Existem operadores semelhantes a estes em C#?

Comment: Na verdade, acho que no C# isso já acontece por padrão, e caso queira que valide os 2 mesmo assim, você deve utilizar um simbolo ao invés de 2. `if (!usuario == null) & (usuario.idade == 18){`

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual a diferença entre os operadores & e &&?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190579/18246)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C# vem da linha do C que prefere símbolos do que palavras para expressar boa parte de sua sintaxe, então:

```
AndAlso  =>  &&
OrElse   =>  ||
```

Eu acho que muito programador usa o operador errado, embora na maioria das vezes dá o mesmo resultado, é diferente usar:

```
And  =>  &
Or   =>  |
```

Os primeiros são lógicos trabalhando apenas com verdadeiro e falso e possuem [curto-circuito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154056/101), os últimos são operadores aritméticos booleanos operando em todos os bits de valores.

[Veja mais sobre as diferenças](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190579/101).

Então em C#:

```
if (Usuario != null && Usuario.Idade == 18) {
    ...
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Operator/And2.cs).

Mas dependendo do que queira, em C# você pode usar outros padrões que evitam a verificação de `null`, inclusive em C# 8 terá a possibilidade de garantir que o objeto não seja nulo.

Comment: Quando eu programava com VB, todos os exemplos em livros e online utilizavam os operadores `And` e `Or`. Acho que por isso que seu uso é mais comum do que `AndAlso` e `OrElse`.

Comment: É, deixa a sua, é útil também, não importa que diz a mesma coisa, colabora para mostrar que é isso mesmo.

Comment: Eu realmente não sabia, muito obrigado pela excelente explicação! :)

Answer (score 6):

O comportamento do operador lógico para *"e" lógico* no C# (`&&`) é o mesmo do operador `AndAlso` que você mencionou. Idem para o operador *"ou" lógico* (`||`) e `OrElse`.

Os operadores `And` e `Or` do Visual Basic são equivalentes aos operadores `&` e `|` do C#, respectivamente.

Acho que todos podemos concordar que isso não é nada óbvio.

Seguindo a resposta do Maniero, vou tentar explicar a diferença aqui.

Os operadores `AndAlso`/`&&` e `OrElse`/`||` funcionam apenas com expressões booleanas e são curto-circuitados.

Os operadores `And`/`&` e `Or`/`|` funcionam como filtros de bits e podem ser utilizados com expressões de vários tipos diferentes - isso é um pouco mais complexo. Mas o importante aqui é que não são curto-circuitados.

A filtragem de bits ocorre da seguinte forma: você alinha dois valores do mesmo tipo em binário e compara os bits em pares, sempre comparando o n-ésimo bit de um valor com o n-ésimo bit de outro valor. O resultado da operação é um terceiro valor em binário com o mesmo tamanho, preenchido de acordo com as seguintes regras:

- Caso a operação seja *"e"*, cada posição do resultado conterá 1 apenas se ambos os inputs tiverem 1 naquela posição, e 0 caso contrário;
- Caso a operação seja *"ou"*, cada posição do resultado conterá 0 apenas se ambos os inputs tiverem 0 naquela posição, e 1 caso contrário.

Para verificar, faça um programa que realize as seguintes operações e mostre os resultados em um console ou caixa de mensagem:

1 & 3:

```
1: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001
3: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011

resultado: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 (1)
```

1 | 3:

```
1: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001
3: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011
resultado: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011 (3)
```

3 & 5:

```
3: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011
5: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0101
resultado: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 (1)
```

3 | 5:

```
3: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011
5: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0101
resultado: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0111 (7)
```

Agora o mais legal: booleanos em .NET são representados por um byte. Os dois valores possíveis são:

```
true: 0000 0001
false: 0000 0000
```

Então: `true & false` resulta em `false`, enquanto `true | false` resulta em `true` (independente da ordem das variáveis).

Quanto ao curto-circuito... Isso é uma característica da maioria das linguagens derivadas do C. A avaliação de expressões lógicas tem duas condições de parada. Ela para imediatamente quando encontra um valor falso para operações do tipo *"e"* (`AndAlso`/`&&`) ou verdadeiro para expressões do tipo *"ou"* (`OrElse`/`||`). Essa característica não é utilizada para os operadores `And`/`&` e `Or`/`|`.

Se você utilizar várias avaliações lógicas em uma única expressão, o programa irá montar uma árvore de expressões - deixo a seu critério pesquisar como os programas fazem isso. O importante é que cada operador vira um nó com dois filhos, e cada filho é uma expressão. O programa então resolve a árvore substituindo cada operador pelo resultado de sua avaliação com seus nós filhos. Se os operadores forem curto-circuitáveis, a árvore pode ter caminhos removidos prematuramente, e esses caminhos jamais serão avaliados. Mas se a árvore contiver apenas operadores não-curto-circuitáveis, ela necessariamente irá avaliar todos os caminhos que tiver.

Comment: Excelente explicação, muito obrigado

Comment: bem completo texto, muito melhor que muito site por aí. show!